# Adding migration site when closing a question

Tags: feature-request, migration

When acting to close a question because it belongs on another SE site, the dialog box generally gives a few default sites, but (apparently) no way to add a new such site.  For instance, I wanted to close a question on Mathematics.SE and migrate it to Cryptography.SE, but the only options provided were MathOverflow, Physics, etc.

How do we add new optional migration sites to the list to be considered when closing a question for migration?